# Does jps lie? If not, what else is this?

Tags: process, docker

I am running dockerized hadoop cdh 4.6.0 with supervisor . I have opened the docker container and tried the following two commands. Got confused a lot.

```
 jps

 103 -- process information unavailable
 291 -- process information unavailable
 107 -- process information unavailable
 449 Jps
```

I read process info unavail means process is zombie. But i checked the status of these processes using in the same container

```
root@1389ca416997:/# /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
   * Hadoop namenode is running
root@1389ca416997:/# /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode status
   * Hadoop secondarynamenode is running
root@1389ca416997:/# /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-datanode status
   * Hadoop datanode is running
```

What causes this ambiguity? or Am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`jps` uses files in `/tmp/hsperfdata_<username>` to determine vmids and info. But sometimes the files are out of date (for whatever reason). Then, `jps` may start to report on stale vmids.

Comment: I don't know this fact. I am seeing this info unavail message after immediately starting the service

Comment: Check the user permissions on the directory, for one thing. Make sure the user the target JVM is running as can write to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have resolved this already but I write here for other people that might be still searching for an answer. The problem is probably related to this [java bug here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/1417962)

A workaround is creating a soft link for the particular process file to a file in the format that jps expects to find.
For example: `ln -s /tmp/hsperfdata_hdfs/553 /tmp/hsperfdata_553`

Alternatively, you could try downgrade your java version. For me this was working up to 1.7.0_65 - Maybe it works with later versions as well, but I start encountering the problem with 1.7.0_79

Also, if you don't mind checking only with the root user you could just run jps with he user that is the owner of the /tmp/hsperfdata_user file. For example: `sudo -u hdfs jps` and `sudo -u mapred jps` will display the processes running for /tmp/hsperfdata_hdfs/ and /tmp/hsperfdata_mapred/ respectively.